# alert not showing exception variable in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to show exception in alert box in asp.net 4. But it is not showing any alert.
I tried these solutions -

```
try{// my code}
catch (Exception ex)
            {             
                //Response.Write("<script>alert('" + Server.HtmlEncode(ex.Message) + "')</script>"); // Not Working
                //Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>"); // Not working
       // Response.Write("<script>alert('" + Server.HtmlEncode(ex.ToString()) + "')</script>"); // Not working
//ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "done", "alert('Error Occured.');", true); // Only this is working.
            }
```

Please suggest any solution to this where I am going wrong.

Thanks and regards,
Rizwan Gazi.

Comment: is there any return in catch ? If yes can you show what are you returning ?

Comment: No. I am not returning anything from catch block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally `Response.Write();` always works. But as you said its not working than

Try this :

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "done", "alert('" + ex.Message.Replace("'", "") + "');", true);
```

Let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: Great dear, it worked fine. Thanks a lot. If you don't mind, can you describe it in brief?

Comment: Glad to know it helped you solve your issue. Happy Coding..!!